# UIBarButtonItem with image and bordered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How is it possible to have something like http://www.nutsaboutmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ShareLinktoFacebook.png

Until now, I've put the same background image for my NavigationBar and my BarButtonItem. The problem is that the button is no longer bordered, you can't do the difference between the NavigationBar and the Button anymore...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_texture.png"];
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[topBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How can I change the background but keep the bordered style ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't set a custom bg image. the border is the bg image and it is either your own or the system.

#### => no way but making your own image

---

Edit:
I THOUGHT for what you describe use tinting: `barButton.tintColor=color` and supply a color either with an alpha or a pattern image made with `colorwithPatternImage`

but... the tinting with a clear color or a pattern doesn't work. this is a bug in the sdk IMO
=> no way but making your own image

Comment: Make my own bordered image on photoshop seems the easiest way

Comment: my answer would have been easy IF it worked... the tinting with a clear color or a pattern doesn't work. this is a  bug in the sdk IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this solution too, without succes :/ thanks for your answer anyway